# Loop to check multiple polygons overlap in r SF package

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a set of polygons  which can overlap each other.
I can find intersection by comparing 1 by 1 polygon each time step by step. by using `st_intersection(x,y)` The problem is my data contains many polygons and  I am prefer to make a loop and include the iteration of polygons which has overall intersect area of each of the intersections. for example 
I need to check condition where one polygons S intersect with n numbers of (p1,p2,p3...)polygons like below and get the sum of overlap of areas like shaded area in yellow or is there any pre-defined function to do this in r:

```
st_intersection(S, p1)
st_intersection(S, p2)
st_intersection(S, p3)
```

[image]

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `st_intersect` function in the `sf` package. Can you make a working example using some sample data?

Comment: I think its st_intersection. Will edit the question

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/12/21/geoms.html) and [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html)